# Query table based on the value of another tables column

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datatable

I have read-only access to a database and there are two tables that contain information I need. both tables have the same numbers in row a in referee to an account. I want to query the result of all accounts in table 1 that have "AD" in column B and where the account has values "4" in column C in of table 2. below is an example.

```
table 1  |
-------- | 
A | B |  |
_______  |
1  AC    |
2  AD    |
3  AC    |
4  AD    |
___________
table 2   |
--------  | 
A | B | C |
__________|
1  AB  4  |
2  AB  5  |
3  AB  4  |
4  AB  4  |
```

I have tried the query

```
SELECT * FROM Table 1 WHERE column B = 'AD' and WHERE column C = '4' FROM TABLE 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use inner Join instead,
Like this:

```
 SELECT 
  t1.* 
 FROM 
  Table1 t1 JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.A = t2.A
 WHERE
  t2.C = 4 AND t1.B = 'AD'
```

Comment: this works now lets say I had a 3rd table two would I write the join part? Would I have "AND Table3 t3 on t1.A = t3.A" and at the end of the WHERE statement " AND t3.C = 'de' "

Comment: Absolutely, You can Add any Other Table to this join Where Column A Exist in New Table

Answer (score 0):

There isn't quite enough info here for me to help.  There isn't common data between the two tables to link them.

Your query above is missing a join between the two tables, and you only need to state the where clause once, additional criteria can be added by using 'and.....'

Comment: COLUMN A in both tables are the same account number.